# How to apply css style on mat-table with modify datasource?

Tags: angular, mat-table

Here is the result I want.

Data would change font color if it contains specific string.

[image]

Code.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'This word need highlight'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'This need highlight'},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'table-text-column-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-text-column-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-text-column-example.html',
})
export class TableTextColumnExample {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  this.DUMMY_DATA.map(obj=>{
  obj.symbol = obj.symbol.replace('highlight','<div style="color:red">highlight</div>');
})
}
```

HTML

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="DUMMY_DATA">
<mat-text-column name="position"></mat-text-column>
<mat-text-column name="name"></mat-text-column>
<mat-text-column name="weight"></mat-text-column>
<mat-text-column name="symbol"></mat-text-column>
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="DUMMY_DISPLAY"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: DUMMY_DISPLAY;"></tr>
</table>
```

But the result seems not what I want. How to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can define your symbol column as follow and dont need to replace dummy data in ts file -

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <span *ngIf="element.symbol.indexOf('highlight') > -1" >

        {{element.symbol.substring(0, element.symbol.indexOf('highlight')) }}
      <span [ngStyle]="{'color':'red'}">highlight</span>
        {{element.symbol.substring( element.symbol.indexOf('highlight')+9, element.symbol.length) }}
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="element.symbol.indexOf('highlight') < 0">
        {{element.symbol }} 
      </span>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```